# TypeORM is not rollback on failure's

Tags: typeorm, rollback, pg

I am new to TypeORM with pg, I have declared a class 'User' extending BaseEntity. I create a instance (user) of the class added values (user.name = 'Arun'), then on user.save() fails with DB constraints. It seems like the TypeORM is not reverting the commit. [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2crR.png) the autogenerated IDs are not incremental since there is no rollback. Have I missed any configuration for rollback? And I would like to know any better example for creating TypeORM models with constructors.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Could you please read the guide to the question and correct your question according to the guide? We need your code or error logs so that community members can respond. [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, TypeORM queries not transactional.

If you want to use transactions to rollback queries if something fail, you need `EntityManager`

```
import {getManager} from "typeorm";

await getManager().transaction(async transactionalEntityManager => {
    await transactionalEntityManager.save(users);
    await transactionalEntityManager.save(photos);
    // ...
});
```

Docs [here](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/transactions.md) for more about TypeORM Transactions.

Comment: Where does users and photos come from?

Comment: @FedericoPeralta they are likely a UserEntity and PhotoEntity types if common naming conventions are followed.